# EC2 instance does not join AWS managed AD Domain automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory, amazon-iam

I am setting up AWS Managed Active Directory and want to set up an EC2 instance (Windows Server 2019 R2) for managing the AD remotely and an AWS Workspace client with a user to log in. But unfortunately despite the appropriate permission, the Ec2 instance does not join the domain automatically.

According to the AWS article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/launching_instance.html

Here are the roles assigned:
**AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ssm:DescribeAssociation",
            "ssm:GetDeployablePatchSnapshotForInstance",
            "ssm:GetDocument",
            "ssm:DescribeDocument",
            "ssm:GetManifest",
            "ssm:GetParameter",
            "ssm:GetParameters",
            "ssm:ListAssociations",
            "ssm:ListInstanceAssociations",
            "ssm:PutInventory",
            "ssm:PutComplianceItems",
            "ssm:PutConfigurePackageResult",
            "ssm:UpdateAssociationStatus",
            "ssm:UpdateInstanceAssociationStatus",
            "ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
            "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
            "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
            "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2messages:AcknowledgeMessage",
            "ec2messages:DeleteMessage",
            "ec2messages:FailMessage",
            "ec2messages:GetEndpoint",
            "ec2messages:GetMessages",
            "ec2messages:SendReply"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

And the other policy as:
**AmazonSSMDirectoryServiceAccess**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ds:CreateComputer",
            "ds:DescribeDirectories"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

With the two policies in place I launched an Instance with AMI ID: ***ami-041306c411c38a789***

**After a successful launch I use the `set` command to review the Domain join but unfortunately I have to do the same manually. Can someone advise why it is so?**
[You can review the Command page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE7yK.png)

Just making sure that the Domain and the Instance are in the same VPC. I am able to check in with the DNS addresses of the domain the instance is recognizing.